# Please let me know how we can super script for [a] in sas with RTF Output?

Tags: sas, rtf

Please let me know how we can super script for **[a]** in ***sas*** with **RTF** Output?

^{super 2} this we can get i want same as ^{super [a]} this is not coming correctly. Please let me know nay other option is there to create this superscript?

Comment: Lots of info out there.  Try https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ODS-RTF-inline-formatting-ESCAPECHAR-and-RTF-control-words-tab/td-p/48063

Comment: Here are instructions on how to format your question. [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are not enough details and no example code was provided illustrating an attempt was made to solve the issue.